# JavaFX - Wait for user to click mouse on element

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, mouseevent, wait

I am implementing a game and I want to ask the player to click on a specific view.

I want my control thread to wait until I get a value back (I have clicked on the view and handled the result). Currently I am doing this by creating a thread, running a method that asks them to click and then entering a while loop that is terminated when the mouse click event changes a variable used in the while loop.

I am writing a game where I have a thread constantly receiving events. On a specific event, I want to prompt the user for a response, but to do this would require me to be on the JavaFX thread (to my knowledge).

Is there a better way of doing this in JavaFX? Thanks!

Comment: What is your control thread?  Is it some thread that you have created or is the JavaFX Application thread?  If it is a thread that you created, can you describe what is for, it's lifecycle and how it works?  Maybe provide a [minimal sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (you can edit your question to update it rather than replying in comments).

Comment: Edited my original question

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools "hidden" in the JDK documentation on threads that can help you resolve this type of issue. Usually when we make a routine code wait for some condition that can proceed we use threads synchronizers.

> I want my control thread to wait until I get a value back [...]

[CountDownLatch](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), [CyclicBarrier](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) and [FutureTask](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) may be classes that can solve your problem. The functionality of these is quite simple. They have the function of stopping threads and release them when some condition is met. The difference in each of these classes is just semantics applied for termination and release threads. Read the documentation of each and see which one is most comfortable to you.

You can also take a look at other sources of study. There is no better source of study in the world (in my opinion) than the content within the book "[Java Concurrency In Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)" by Brian Goetz. I assure you that you will become able to easily manipulate threads if you buy this book (or at least gain an incredible knowledge on the subject). Make it clear that you do not need to buy the book to solve your current problem. Buying the book is just my suggestion for you to have more knowledge about threads. You probably will solve your problem by looking at the documentation of classes that synchronize threads I mentioned.

Good luck in your projects. ;)